# Replacing items in 1 list to items in another list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to replace items in 1 list of lists with items from another list of lists.

```
    alist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
    blist = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i]]
```

Basically, I want to replace the items in alist with it's blist counterpart. For example, if someone chose 1 in alist, I want to replace it with the same index from blist which would be a.

```
    alist = [[a,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> z = [(i, x.index(item)) for i, x in enumerate(alist) if item in x][0]
>>> alist[z[0]][z[1]] = blist[z[0]][z[1]]
>>> alist
[['a', 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/5TKFJ)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to loop over both lists together, then loop over each subgroup to replace the matched choice.

For lockstep iteration, the *[zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)* function is your best friend.  For transforming lists a *[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)* is a great tool.  Here's how to use them:

```
>>> alist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> blist = [[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]
>>> choice = 1
>>> alist = [[(bx if ax==choice else ax) for ax, bx in zip(aseq, bseq)] for aseq, bseq in zip(alist, blist)]
>>> alist
[[10, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

What is nice about this approach is that it can do multiple replacements (for example, if *alist* contains several `1` entries, they all get replaced with their corresponding entries in the *blist*).

Another nice feature is that the `ax==choice` decision can easily be replaced with other predicates (for example, `ax in {2, 5, 8}` will search for multiple substitution targets in a single pass).  Another example is `ax % 2 == 0` which would make *blist* replacements for any *alist* value that is even).

Answer (score 0):

Crude but easily explained:

```
blist = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
alist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,2], [7,8,9]]
x = 2

for y in xrange(len(alist)):
    if x in alist[y]:
        i = alist[y].index(x)
        alist[y][i] = blist[y][i]

print alist
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'b', 3], [4, 5, 'f'], [7, 8, 9]]
```